# How to count the number of lucky numbers between L and H inclusive?

Tags: python

I've completed a codingame assessment but i was not able to pass all tests on one challenge about lucky numbers. I need some help.

**Definition**: a lucky number is a number that contains either `6`s or `8`s in its digits but not both.
For example `16`, `38`, `666` are lucky numbers. `234`, `687` are not.

**Task**: Print the number of lucky numbers between `L` and `H` inclusive.

**Constraints**:

- `L < H`
- Memory: `512MB`
- Time: `6 seconds`

Here's what I did (I chose Python as programming language)

```py
def is_lucky(nbr):
    nbr = [*str(nbr)]
    if '6' in nbr and '8' in nbr:
        return False
    if '6' in nbr or '8' in nbr:
        return True
    return False

n_lucky_number = 0
for number in range(L, H + 1):
    n_lucky_number += is_lucky(number)
print(n_lucky_number)
```

I failed the tests where `L` and `H` are big (or the gap between) due to timeout.

`L, H = 1, 1000000000000000000`

`L, H = 92871036442, 3363728910382456`

Could someone help me to optimize my code?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use loops in such tasks unless necessary. Instead, try to think logically and find a formula that leads to the result.

Comment: You need a whole new approach. The first thing to realize is that `lucky(L,H) = lucky(0,H) - lucky(0,L-1)`.

Comment: @AnnZen I don't think there is a programming language which can pass such big tests at all if to use such inefficient approach.

Comment: @user3386109 it seems to me your solution will take even longer time than the OP's solution because the [0, L - 1] segment will be processed one more time.

Comment: @DemianWolf Given that `lucky(0,N)` is an O(logN) function, the solution is much faster.

Comment: @user3386109 I disagree. Let L be 5 and H be 10. Your solution will check 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and then 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 again. While OP's solution will check just 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. You get 15 "lucky" checks vs. only 6.

Comment: @DemianWolf Your proposed implementation of `lucky(0,N)` is O(N). The correct implementation of `lucky(0,N)` is O(logN).

Comment: @user3386109 How do you find O(logN)?

Comment: @user3386109 Could you share with us the implementation that gives you O(logN)?

Comment: @user3386109 in this case, the complexity of algorithm doesn't count, because the range from 0 to L - 1 will be counted twice anyway.

Comment: @Dmitri K. Sifoua the O(logN) and O(N) is called [alghorithm complexity](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html)

Comment: @DimitriK.Sifoua Here's a incomplete description of the approach. You'll need to fill in the details, and extend the algorithm to larger numbers. Determine how many lucky numbers there are in each hundred when the first digit is **not** 6 or 8 (call that Hx), as well as how many lucky numbers there are in each hundred when the first digit **is** 6 or 8 (call that Hy). So if you're computing `lucky(0,753)` the answer is `5*Hx + Hy + other`. `5*Hx` covers the numbers from 100 to 599. `Hy` covers the numbers from 600 to 699. And `other` covers the numbers from 0 to 99, and 700 to 753.

Comment: @user3386109 [proof](https://repl.it/repls/SpiffyWindingEditor#main.py). Your previous solution works 1.5x longer than the OP's (for big L) and takes almost the same time for small L.

Comment: @user3386109 that's a good idea

Comment: Upon further review, it seems like you can simplify a little bit since 0-99 can be treated as three digit numbers with 0 as the first digit (leading zeros don't change whether a number is lucky or not). That reduces the calculation to `6*Hx + Hy + other` where `other` covers the numbers from 700 to 753.

Comment: Minor optimizations: 1. In large numbers (like those you are failing in) a better for loop can help you, e.g. loop until 6600, and from 6700 to 6800, and then again from 6900 to 8600, and so on. This should cut ~4% from your runtime
2. Are threads legit? If so, they can help

Comment: Possible major optimization: memoization. Each lucky number is a prefix to another one, or to a bad one. Every number with more than one 6/8 is a prefix to a unlucky number. Using these prefixes can save you some time (it might not, as it would complicate your function,and have the overhead of updating a data struct)

Answer (score 2):

```
def coo(a):
    b=str(a)
    l=len(b)
    c=[]
    count=0
    for i,j in enumerate(b):
        d=l-i-1
        for k in range(int(j)):
            if k==6 or k==8:
                if k==6 and "8" not in c:
                    count=count+9**d
                elif k==8 and "6" not in c:
                    count=count+9**d    
            elif "6" not in c and "8" not in c:
                count=count+2*((9**d)-(8**d))
            elif "6" in c or "8" in c:
                count=count+9**d 
        
        c.append(j)        
        if "6" in c and "8" in c:
            break
    return(int(count))
L=21345323634
H=8392440035734    
print(coo(H+1)-coo(L))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting problem and @sulav shrestha has already delivered a working algorithm. Unfortunately his answer lacks some explanation and the code itself can be cleaner.

As others have pointed out, you have to come up with a formula in order to perform with big numbers.

@user3386109 rightfully pointed out that `lucky(L,H) = lucky(0,H) - lucky(0,L-1)`. From there let's see how many lucky numbers there are between 0 and any given number.
In a decimal base, any number can be written like a sum of power of ten:

```
12345 = 1e4 + 2e3 + 3e2 + 4e1 + 5e0
```

So let's calculate the number of lucky numbers between 0 and `10^n`. It comes down to count the possible combinations of n-digits numbers with either:

- no `8` and at least one `6`
- no `6` and at least one `8`

The number of combination with no `8` is `9^n` (you get to choose among 9 possibilities for each of the n digits).
Then you remove all combinations NOT containing any `6`: `8^n`.

So the number of lucky numbers between 0 and `10^n` is `2*(9^n-8^n)`.

From there you can iterate over your digits from left to right and count:

```
import time
def magic_numbers_until(num):
    num_str=str(num)
    str_len=len(num_str)
    c=[]
    count=0
    for i,digit in enumerate(num_str):          # we're going from left to right in num
        power_ten=str_len-i-1
        for k in range(int(digit)):             # summing all magic numbers for this power of ten
            if (k==6 or k==8                    # if 6 (resp. 8) was already seen,
                or "6" in c or "8" in c):       # you just calculate the combinations without 8 (resp. 6)
                count=count+9**power_ten 
            else:                               # the case described in my answer
                count=count+2*(9**power_ten-8**power_ten)
        
        c.append(digit)        
        if "6" in c and "8" in c:               # if 6 and 8 are in num, all remaining combinations will be non-magic
            break
    return(int(count))
    
L=1
H=1000000000000000000
t0 = time.time()  
print(magic_numbers_until(H+1)-magic_numbers_until(L))
print(time.time()-t0)
```

Answer (score -2):

6 seconds? That seems really hard in Python, usually slow compared to C, Java etc. Even though I haven't figured out a way that passes the test, there are a few places you can improve:

#### 1. is_lucky

`nbr` can be just converted to `str`, no need to unpack into `list`. `str` supports `in`.
Use the fact that in mathematical calcs, `True==1`, `False==0`.
E.g. A is `'6' in nbr`, B is `'8' in nbr`:
Both are true, *A+B=2*

One is true, *A+B=1*

Both are false, *A+B=0*
So we can just check if *A+B == 1*.

Before:

```py
def is_lucky(nbr):
    nbr = [*str(nbr)]
    if '6' in nbr and '8' in nbr:
        return False
    if '6' in nbr or '8' in nbr:
        return True
    return False
```

After:

```py
def is_lucky(nbr):
    nbr = str(nbr)
    return ('6' in nbr) + ('8' in nbr) == 1
```

#### 2. The loop

If the number now has checked `False`, we can improve it.
If the final digit is less than 5, increment 6-n%10.
For example, *311* isn't a lucky number. So of course 312~315 aren't, too, so just add directly to *316* by *6-1=5*.
Why not <6? 5 adds 1 no matter what, so we don't need it :]

Before:

```py
n_lucky_number = 0
for number in range(L, H + 1):
    n_lucky_number += is_lucky(number)
print(n_lucky_number)
```

After:

```py
number, s = L, 0
while n <= H:
    x = is_lucky(number)
    n_lucky_number += x
    m = number % 10
    if not x and m < 5:
        number += 6-m
    else:
        number += 1
print(n_lucky_number)
```